# Spark on Amazon EMR: "Timeout waiting for connection from pool"

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark job on a small three server Amazon EMR 5 (Spark 2.0) cluster. My job runs for an hour or so, fails with the error below. I can manually restart and it works, processes more data, and eventually fails again.

My Spark code is fairly simple and is not using any Amazon or S3 APIs directly. My Spark code passes S3 text string paths to Spark and Spark uses S3 internally.

My Spark program just does the following in a loop: Load data from S3 -> Process -> Write data to different location on S3.

My first suspicion is that some internal Amazon or Spark code is not properly disposing of connections and the connection pool becomes exhausted.

```
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:618)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1015)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:991)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:212)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:780)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1428)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:313)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:85)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:487)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:226)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:195)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy45.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:837)
            at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
            ... 41 more
```

Comment: For further help, you'd need to provide a code sample  and / or tell us what language your'e using for your code. There is mention of this type of problem elsewhere on SO, and they wrote a snippet to dispose of the lingering S3 connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782937/connectionpooltimeoutexception-when-iterating-objects-in-s3

Comment: I'm encountering a very similar issue with Spark 1.6.1 in AWS. From the debug logs, I can see that each executor fails to release a connection when a task ends. That is: the executor might start processing spark task 5, and while processing that task it will make multiple calls to S3, then close the connections, but then when the task ends (and it wants to start task 6), one connection isn't closed. So if the connection pool size is n, I get this error when the executor starts its n+1 task.

Comment: Getting this issue too, how can I close S3 connections when I only use Dataframewriter's and Dataframereader's?

Comment: Same problem here. Did anyone find a solution? Thanks

Comment: We are facing the same issue anyone found any solutions ?

Answer (score 14):

I encountered this issue with a very trivial program on EMR (read data from S3, filter, write to S3).

I could solve it by using the S3A file system implementation and setting `fs.s3a.connection.maximum` to `100` to have a bigger connection pool.
(default is `15`; see [Hadoop-AWS module: Integration with Amazon Web Services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) for more config properties)

This is how I set the configuration:

```
// in Scala
val hc = sc.hadoopConfiguration

// in Python (not tested)
hc = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

// setting the config is the same for both languages
hc.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hc.setInt("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", 100)
```

To make it work, the S3 URIs passed to Spark have to start with `s3a://...`

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. The above did not seem to make any difference for me. We are definitely using s3a URLs.

Comment: The documentation says "The “classic” s3: filesystem for storing objects in Amazon S3 Storage. NOTE: s3: is being phased out. Use s3n: or s3a: instead."

Comment: @Markus What documentation are you referring to? Amazon writes in their recent EMR documentation _"The `s3a` protocol is not supported. We suggest you use `s3` in place of `s3a`."_ (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html)

Comment: @hiddenbit: Check this out https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

Comment: @Markus: This page shows ways how to connect to S3 from Hadoop in general – there `s3a` is the way to go. But this question is about accessing S3 from AWS EMR, here `s3` should be used, since EMR provides the proprietary Amazon EMRFS for accessing S3 with higher performance.

Comment: @hiddenbit i'm getting this error using the s3:// prefix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This issue may also be resolved while remaining on EMRFS by setting fs.s3.maxConnections to something larger than the default 500 in emrfs-site config

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-timeout-connection-wait/

If using Java SDK to spin up an EMR cluster you can set this using the `withConfigurations` method (which is much easier than doing it manually by modifying files). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595058/1586965

You can check this has been set correctly by using the Configurations tab in EMR, e.g.

[image]

Comment: In @hiddenbit 's solution he uses `sc.hadoopConfiguration`, which allows us to alter this in code.  Do you know if we can use that approach for `fs.s3.maxConnections`? since we want to automate job running, and modifying this file on every node is very fiddly.

Comment: If you read to the end of the linked page it tells you how to set it for an entire cluster on start up.

Comment: Ah yes, I skimmed that as it looked like part of step 5 (poor formatting).